# jQuery Limit Global Namespace

Tags: jquery, javascript-namespaces

Currently I have all my JavaScript functions in a single function so the I don't pollute the global namespace.

e.g.

```
var App = function() {

    function a() {
    }

    return {};
}();
```

Now I would like to use jQuery so I would like this wrapped in the following:

```
(function (window, document, $) {
   ...
}(window, document, jQuery));
```

I have tried wrapping the var App = function () {} in the jQuery function, however this causes problems when I have AJAX setting properties on App.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a separate anonymous function, you can just pass the `window`, `document`, and `jQuery` directly into app:

```
var App = function(window, document, $) {
    function a() {
    }
}(window, document, jQuery);
```

*Alternatively*, you can declare `App` in the global namespace, but define it in the jQuery closure, like this:

```
var App = null;

(function (window, document, $) {
    App = function() {
        function a() {
        }
    };
}(window, document, jQuery));
```

Note that in both these examples, I've removed the `return {}` and in the second one I made the function non-self-calling. That part of the structure looks like copy-and-paste cruft and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var App = function(window, document, $) {

      function a() {
      }

      return {};

}(window, document, jQuery);
```